# SQL Computed Column If Statement

Tags: sql-server, case, calculated-columns

This is not working. Still getting division by zero error. Any ideas?

```
case when [games]=NULL then (0) 
     when [games]=(0) then (0) 
     else CONVERT([decimal](18,2),CONVERT([float],[goalsAG],(0))/CONVERT([float],[games],(0)),(0)) end
```

Comment: Firstly, don't see how `[games]=NULL` would even work.  Should be `[games] IS NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

You can never use = with NULL, use IS NULL.

And simplified further:

```
(case when isnull([games], 0) = 0 then (0) else CONVERT(decimal,CONVERT([float],[goalsAG],(0))/CONVERT([float],[games],(0)),(0)) end)
```